Как связать сервис с иконкой в WP?

Всем привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как связать сервис с иконкой в WordPress? Для электрогитары привязка есть - выбран icon-electric-guitar, а для бас-гитары нет.

Какой "сервис" и какое он имеет отношения к иконке? Иконка не привязывается ни к какому сервису.

В настройках темы можно определенному сервису назначить иконку. Это делается для того, чтобы на фронте список сервисов содержал не только их названия, но и иконки.
В теме melodyschool реализовано так

"сервис" - это сторонняя услуга (в интернете напр). А что у тебя на сайте - это НЕ сервис. Не путай людей, а объясняй с конкретикой.

Разобрался. Нужно было поменять шрифты. Сделал это через этот сайт

Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].
